# Plotting pie chart using Django Cahrtit

Tags: python, django, pie-chart

I am trying to plot pie chart using Django chartit. Below is my code. I have a model racktestresult with fields PassNumber, FailNumber and Date. I am looking for a formula to plot a pie chart of only the sum of PassNumbers and sum of FailNumbers.

```
ds = DataPool(
        series=[
            {
                'options': {
                'source': racktestresult.objects.values('Date').annotate(
                    Pass=Sum('PassNumbers'), Fail=Sum('FailNumbers'))},
                'terms': [
                    'Date', 'Pass', 'Fail'
                ]
            }
        ]
    )

    cht3 = Chart(
        datasource=ds,
        series_options=[
            {
                'options': {
                    'type': 'pie', 'stacking': False,
                    'options3d': {'enabled': True, 'alpha': 45, 'beta': 0}
                }, 'terms': {'Date': ['Fail']}
            }
        ],
        chart_options={
            'title': {'text': 'Pass/Fail - Pie Chart'}
        }
    )
```

[image: Pie Chart generated by above code]

What I am trying to get is just PassNumbers and FailNumbers from racktestresult model like below. How can I achieve that?

[image]

Comment: What is exactly your problem? Plus, you may need to give more code.

Comment: I am trying to plot a pie chart using django chartit. I have a django model racktestresult with fields PassNumbers and FailNumbers and Date and there is some data in that fields. I would like to plot a pie chart from that data. Here is the link. "http://chartit.shutupandship.com/demo/chart/basic-pie/ ". What I am trying is to plot only sum of all passnumbers and sum of fail numbers.

Comment: Add your informations directly to the post (use the edit button).
Add what you want to do to it, what you did (your code) and what you got (a detailled result). That's not clear thus far.